# Hiding a div with toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this button in html

```
<tr><td>
    <button class="btn cmt_list" name="cmtList" id="cmt-'.$row['uid'].'"value = "hide/show"/>Show</button>
</td></tr>
```

Upon clicking, I'd like to show/hide the div. I would like the div to be hidden by default.

```
<div class='commentbox' id='comments-{$row['uid']}'></div>
```

As of now, my javascript looks like this

```
var toggle = function() {
    var mydiv = document.getElementById('newpost');
    if (mydiv.style.display === 'block' || mydiv.style.display === '')
        mydiv.style.display = 'none';
    else
        mydiv.style.display = 'block'
}
```

Comment: You have this post tagged with `jQuery` are you using jQuery?

Comment: And what is the problem here?

Comment: I think you can get rid of mydiv.style.display === '' because it will always return something

Comment: If you're already using jquery (which this code suggests you are NOT), you can just call `$('#item_id').toggle();` - whats the question?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5U9jN/ pure JS, you want this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to write your own toggle function. You can do it easily with the jQuery toggle function.

Here's the HTML. Setting `display: none` will make it hidden by default.

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display: none">
    Hello this is my div
</div>
<button id="myBtn">Toggle Div</button>
```

Here's the jQuery.

```
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
    $('#myDiv').toggle();
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eL2AU/

---

You can also do it with JavaScript alone, like so:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
btn.onclick = function() {
    var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    if (d.style.display === "none") {
        d.style.display = "block";   
    } else {
         d.style.display = "none";   
    }
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eL2AU/1/

Comment: @JayBlanchard Agreed, although based on the complexity of the question, jQuery might be something OP should take advantage of...

Comment: Maybe @DrydenLong, but if he isn't doing a bunch of other stuff in the page requiring jQuery it would be overkill.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, but for someone just starting out, that overkill is worth the simplicity of using jQuery. Not too mention, just the base jQuery library isn't *that* big of a bandwidth killer. jQuery UI, now that's another story...

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the wrong ID to `document.getElementById()`. Your div has ID `comments-{$row['uid']}` but you are looking for an element with ID of `newpost`.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is hiding the div before it is clicked then put this before your function

```
$('#myDiv').hide();
```